# Second Network Interface in Subnet of default route

Tags: networking, 16.04, iptables, subnet

I've got a 16.04 server with interface **em1** in my companys **a.b.0.0/16** subnet AB. For reasons reasons I can't change, there is a protected subsubnet ABC within this range called **a.b.c.0/24** which I only can reach by adding a second network interface **em2**.

So I connected em2 and brought it up getting a lot of AB packages on em2 (where I expected only ABC packets). And the em2 address is not reachable by computers of the ABC subnet.

`ip r s` shows me

```
 default via a.b.0.1 dev em1 
 a.b.0.0/16 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src a.b.0.1 
 a.b.c.0/24 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src a.b.c.1
```

What am I missing?

Why are there a lot of packages on em2 as if I am bridging both networks (which I don't want).

There is no ipv4/6 forwarding enabled in sysconf or /proc/sys/net/ipv4/.

Thanks in advance,

Harry